# Exception when adding CustomMarshaler field to binary struct

Tags: c#, marshalling

I am building a binary data structure representing a file header.

The structure is declared as:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, Pack =1, Size =4096)]
public struct FILE_HEADER
{
...
}
```

This struct contains a number of marshaled strings and arrays and other native fields like UIn32. Among these also two windows FILETIME fields (8 bytes). As long as I define these fields as Int64 all works perfectly. But I would like to marshal them into DateTime. If I do so I get an Exception (trying to call Marshal.SizeOf or OffsetOf) stating "System.ArgumentException
HResult=0x80070057
Message=Type 'FILE_HEADER' cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure; no meaningful size or offset can be computed."

Since help states that CustomMarshaler can only operate on reference types, I did encapsulate DateTime into a class FILETIME, and the Marshalling part looks like follows:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(FileTimeMarshaler))]
public FILETIME LastWritten;
```

And the custom marshaler looks like this:

internal class FileTimeMarshaler : ICustomMarshaler
{
public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string pstrCookie)
=> new FileTimeMarshaler();

```
public FileTimeMarshaler() { }

public void CleanUpManagedData(object ManagedObj) { }

public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData) { }

public int GetNativeDataSize()
{
  return 8;
}

public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj)
{
  throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
{
  Int64 ft = Marshal.ReadInt64(pNativeData);
  return new FILETIME(ft);
}
```

}

Finally the FILETIME class to be complete:

```
 public class FILETIME
  {
    public DateTime FileTime { get; }
    public FILETIME(Int64 t)
    {
      // FileTime = new DateTime();
      FileTime = DateTime.FromFileTime(t);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It is an Int64, *not* an IntPtr and not an object.  It is hackable as long as the interop is 64-bits, but use pNativeData.ToInt64() instead of Marshal.ReadInt64().  Can't be made to work if the interop is 32-bits.  
Far too fugly to avoid using the simple solution, make the field private and add a public property with a getter that uses DateTime.FromFileTime().

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but that's unfortunately not correct. Of course it is an Int64 not an IntPtr. What you suggest is that the FILETIME would be transfered by value inside of the IntPtr, that would however not work as IntPtr is 32bit if the process is 32-bit.

Also from the manual: "pNativeData : A pointer to the unmanaged data to be wrapped"

Finally it does not come into play, because MarshalNativeToManaged is never called up to the exception. Even GetNativeDataSize is never called and it lokks like even the Marshaller is never constructed.

Comment: Some more info. I have some code to check that the fields are correctly positioned at expected offsets and then get the size of the structure. Every of these code lines fails:
      ((int)Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(FILE_HEADER), "FileName")).Should().Be(48);
      ((int)Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(FILE_HEADER), "LastWritten")).Should().Be(72);
      ((int)Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(FILE_HEADER), "Checksum")).Should().Be(248);

      int headerSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FILE_HEADER));

Comment: I verified now via several ways (breakpoint, division by 0 of a field) that the constructor of the custom marshaller is never called, so at least it is not surprising that the mars haler cannot compute the struct offsets. The question, is "why"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, looks like the easy answer is that `UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler` cannot be used on fields. Unfortunately, the Microsoft documentation is inconsistent in this point.

The documentation of `UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler` states:

> You can use this member on any reference type. This member is valid
> for parameters and return values only. It cannot be used on fields.

While the `ICustomMarshaler` interface documentation states:

> To use a custom marshaler, you must apply the MarshalAsAttribute
> attribute to the parameter or **field** that is being marshaled.

So I reverted to a private `Int64` field with a public property doing the conversion:

```
private Int64 _LastWritten;
public DateTime LastWritten { get { return DateTime.FromFileTime(_LastWritten); } }
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit will keep this in mind for the future.